# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 SecretKeyFactory not available Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I am getting `NoSuchAlgorithmException` at runtime in my android app even though I am using JDK 8.

Here is the line that makes error

> SecretKeyFactory factory =
>   SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")

Java Version

```
 java version "1.8.0_161"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

I have given the JDK path in Android Studio also at

> File > Project Sturcture > SDK

Location.

API Level is 26

Comment: You need to check different places in order to validate if the algorithm is available.

For instance if you want to check which phones have this algorithm you refer to this page

https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html

And there you see that you need API level 26 and above so Oreo and above.

Comment: Availability for oracle java 8 could be found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html

Comment: API Level is 26. As per the documentation PBKDF2withHmacSHA512 should be supported 26+